# What ffmpeg command line matches the one YouTube uses?

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

I am trying to use the same command line YouTube uses for quality etc. in H.264/MP4 containers. I have been working on converting videos into multiple formats, scales, sizes and adjusting the bit rates and audio rates to match what YouTube said they use.

In a nut shell here is what I use:

```
-pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -aspect 16:9 -r 24000/1001 -movflags +faststart
```

Now if I am to elaborate on why these values are what they are You should first see what YouTube tell us themselves what they use here.

- https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en
- https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-ffmpeg-mapping

So let's go into detail

1. moov atom at the front of the file (Fast Start)
2. Channels: Stereo or Stereo + 5.1
3. Sample rate 96khz or 48khz
4. Progressive scan (no interlacing)
5. High Profile
6. 2 consecutive B frames
7. Closed GOP. GOP of half the frame rate.
8. CABAC
9. Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0
10. Frame rate
11. YouTube uses 16:9 aspect ratio players.
12. Audio codec: AAC-LC

In ffmpeg's command line these become the following.

1. `-movflags +faststart`
2. `-ac 2`
3. `-ar 48000`
4. **Not sure what the command for this is.** (FFMPEG By default encoding is progressive.)
5. `-profile:v high -level 4.0`
6. `-bf 2` (FFMPEG's default is 16.)
7. `-g 12` or `-g 15` varies on YouTube's FPS. (The default, 12, works for 24-25 fps. For NTSC and 30 fps, select 15.* FFMPEG option: `-g`, Not sure what youtube's default FPS is if it is 24 or 30. I assume 24 since the default 12 would be half the frame rate and 15 if their frame rate is 30.)
8. `-coder 1` (By default CABAC is the entropy encoder used by x264.)
9. `-pix_fmt yuv420p` (My opinion everyone needs to add this mandatory, or perhaps all non-FFmpeg based players do not support proper decoding of YUV 4:2:2 or YUV 4:4:4. So yuv 4:2:0 is required.)
10. `-r 24000/1001` (Assume YouTube's default frame rate is 24.)
11. `-aspect 16:9`
12. `-acodec libfaac`

But I know there are probably some commands I am missing or need changing if anyone would be so kind to help. And correct / tell me what I need to change / add.

Because I want to use a baseline profile I do not use CABAC, GOP or B-Frames in my command line, since they all become disabled and irrelevant.

Comment: 1. Posting the PHP source here probably won't help a lot. Not everybody understands PHP, so even they know the answer they can't answer. 2. Encoding 4K in baseline is incredibly dumb. 3. Don't set `-aspect`. It will mess up your encoding.

Comment: Thanks i edited my code above and put $fcmd into it so i can control the command line properties for each size/quality of video being generated 360p 480 etc under 4k and 2k should i set them both to use -profile:v high ?

Comment: The YouTube link you have just shows how **you** should code your videos for uploading to YouTube. It's not necessarily what **they** are using internally (and I know this for a fact). If you want 24 FPS, why are you using 24000/1001?

Comment: So nobody knows what command line they use internally ? I read thats how you set the rate to be 24 ?

Comment: Well, YouTube people know, of course, and a few researchers with whom they work together (I've talked to one at a conference recently). You can also just download MP4s from YouTube in all kinds of formats (itags), e.g. using `youtube-dl` and then analyze the bitstream yourself regarding GOPs, B-frame types, et cetera. The real question is: why do you want to match these settings so closely? What's the use case? (If you want 24 fps, just set `-r 24`...)

Comment: The usage is for a multimedia site i am building i have looked at videos youtube outputs and i have come to the conclusion these settings could be different is why i am asking. Some settings in youtube videos i notice consistency in are these, "-ar 44100", "-ac 2", "-ab 128k". According to wikipedia they use the libfaac audio encoder and as of these other commands i am not sure since they vary so much on different quality/sizes of video.

Comment: `-r 24000/1001` is 23.98 fps, which is supported but...